# Java Web Service creates large number of Tomcat sessions

Tags: java, web-services, session, tomcat, java-web-start

I have Java Web Service running in Tomcat on Linux. The JWS will continue to create new sessions for each call. I would like to remove / kill the sessions once the user has completed the WebService call. Does anyone have experience with this? I can't decrease the timeout as the WebService is part of a larger app.

Answer (score 1):

Either move the WS to its own Web Application  (as should probably have been done in the first place) and set that up separate, install an HTTP filter intercepting calls to the WS and closing sessions after the response from the WS has been sent, or have the WS itself close the sessions.

Comment: Thanks jwenting. Moving the server to its own web app (agreed... it should have been done already) isn't an option at this point. I am not sure how to close the session in the JWS... any ideas?

Comment: @BillT if you've access to the HttpSession in your WS handler or a servlet filter, you can close it. See the API docs.

Answer (score 0):

So as a workaround for this I created a method in my JWS and I am calling it before returning data from the methods. Kind of crude, but it works...

```
  private void dropWSSession(){
MessageContext messageContext = MessageContext.getCurrentContext();
HttpServlet servlet = (HttpServlet)messageContext.getProperty(HTTPConstants.MC_HTTP_SERVLET);
ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext)servlet.getServletContext();
HttpSession session =((HttpServletRequest)messageContext.getProperty(HTTPConstants.MC_HTTP_SERVLETREQUEST)).getSession();
session.invalidate();
```

}